# Using StructureMap, when a default concrete type is defined in one registry, can it be redefined in another registry?

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, structuremap, ioc-container

In the project I'm working on I have a StructureMap registry for the main web project and another registry for my integration tests.  During some of the tests I wire up the web project's registry, so that I can get objects out of the container for testing.

In one case I want to be able to replace a default concrete type from the web registry with one in the test registry.

Is this possible?

How do you do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, the container will serve up which ever type is last defined (according to my tests).  I theorize (but I am unsure) that my mistake was that I called the `IInitializationExpression.Scan` mechanism after I registered some type and it got reregistered back to it's original setting.

Comment: Can we see the code please?  I need help doing EXACTLY THIS and I am super new to StructureMap

Comment: @PrisonerZERO - Sorry, I don't have an example because I'm not really using StructureMap anymore, this answer was more than  7 years ago. You need to make sure its the last registration that occurs for that type is the one you want.

Comment: Yeah, I dont really care for StructureMap...Im a Unity fan, myself. :-)

Answer (score 1):

In a similar situation I created a NestedContainer (`Container.GetNestedContainer()`) and overwrote the type there. I then use the nested container to resolve the type.

That keeps the original configuration intact but allows for such overriding.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the `.With()` when you use `GetInstance()`?

Otherwise, you also use `Container.Inject()`.